# Nginx memcached_pass directive unknown

Tags: nginx, memcached

I am setting up a new server instance on AWS and have run into something I don't know how to handle. I've set up exactly the same config on digital ocean before and there issue does not occur at all. When I execute `nginx -t` to check the config, I get this back, with a reference to the line that contains the `memcached_pass` (see conf snippet further down).

`nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "memcached_pass"`

Am I missing some package that needs to be installed? Checked the documentation out, but couldn't really find anything that would explain this. This is the same setup I use on Ubuntu on my other server.

The only difference I know of between the machines are the Ubuntu versions 
14.04.1 LTS on this one and 12.04.4 LTS on the ones that work. Could that have any impact?

Config:

```
location /embed/view {
    default_type "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    set $memcached_key $uri;
    memcached_pass 127.0.0.1:11211;
    error_page 404 502 @fallback_embed;
}
```

Comment: Where did you get nginx from?

Comment: @michaelhampton I installed it by `apt-get install -y nginx`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install at least `nginx-full` package to have memcached module included. The `nginx` package contains only a small subset of extra modules.

Comment: It lead me in the right direction. Seems like some dependency is broken for nginx-full on 14 so I downgraded and went with 12 instead and it seems to work no problem now.

The issue I had when trying to install nginx-full in 14 was 
`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nginx-full : Depends: libgd2-noxpm but it is not installable or libgd2-xpm but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`